# Completely custom Magento interface without shop

Tags: php, magento

I have been searching but have not found much information on this. Would it be possible to completely override Magento's frontend interface? What I mean with this is completely remove the shopping cart, menu's, product listings, everything, and replace with a completely customized interface, which will not be used for a eCommerce portal.

I just found out that our customer does not in fact want a eCommerce solution, although we have built a lot of functionality on Magento and it would be a shame to have to re-write EVERYTHING on another platform and still build a ordering framework as well.

So my question is this, can you build a theme on Magento that only shows parts of the system completely unrelated to the actual 'shop' and where would I find information to figure out how to do this? I'd like to keep the custom frontend in Magento to easily re-use the product view blocks, etc. but Magento itself is not a system our client wants.

I have thought of an alternative where the Magento shop is merely placed in a sub-directory and used as a sort of 'engine' to run the eCommerce side of the system and building a completely different system which integrates with Magento, the downside of this of course being that we would have to rewrite completed work as well.

What would be the best route to follow?

Comment: What sort of functionality did you build that would make you want to keep it? Are you still using any part of the core to store entities (e.g. customers or catalog data).

Comment: @beeplogic custom EAV entities, other business processes like repair orders, shop traffic reporting. We'd hate to have to redevelop these features on another custom platform.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to go about it:

- Edit the homepage via the backend and enter the following code in to it:

`{{block type="catalog/product" template="page/homepage.phtml"}}` this will allow you to display products on the page.

- Make sure that when you enter the code you can see html markup (and not just the output)
- Make a completely customized webpage showing whatever you want